# How to color button background when it is disabled

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-appcompat, android-button

I want to color my button that is defined in a fragment. I created new style (which I use as a theme in the button) and defined "colorAccent" for enabled state, "colorButtonNormal" for disabled and parent of this style is "Widget.AppCompat.Button". I want it to be coloured exactly as it is written in colorButtonNormal when button is disabled.

```
    <style name="Material.Button.Primary" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/color_disabled</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_primary</item>
    </style>
```

```
        <Button
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/button_text"
            android:textAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Text"
            android:theme="@style/Material.Button.Primary" />
```

When the button is enabled it has correct color from colorAccent. When user clicks on it, it becomes disabled and should be gray (#b2b2b2) but it becomes a little bit lighter (#E7E7E7). It seems like it takes color that I defined and mixes with white color.

I tried to change style's parent and did some changes in style and button's attributes as it is written in some guides from the internet but nothing worked. My current solution is to set colorButtonNormal to #000000. When button is disabled, it becomes #B9B9B9.

Comment: I am not aware of any attribute to do so . Can you try calling `Button.setBackgroundTintList(null) ` at runtime and check .

Comment: @ADM, it is now pure white in both states

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me if I am wrong but as far I understand correctly, you want to achieve different colours for enabled/disabled states.

**UPDATE**

For keeping the material effect you can use styling with `Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored` and create theme with specified colours:

```
<Button
.
.
.
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:theme="@style/CustomButton"/>
```

And create theme, where `colorButtonNormal` is for disabled state

```
<style name="CustomButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/color_disabled</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_enabled</item>
</style>
```

**Old without material effect**

You can try using selector like:

custom_button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:drawable="@color/color_disabled" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:drawable="@color/color_enabled/>
</selector>
```

and then in your xml for button:

```
<Button
.
.
.
android:background="@drawable/custom_button" />
```

Comment: Yeah I think you are wrong here .By Overriding `android:background` Button will lose Material effect ..

Comment: I have already used style and theme as in your modified answer. It doesn't work. As I said, color that you define in colorButtonNormal becomes lighter when button is disabled